# jQuery Wait for two triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-events, eventtrigger

I have two async functions, the first triggers event 1, the second triggers event 2 on finish.

I want to execute my third function only after the two events has been triggered.
How can I do it in a simple way?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried already? Also, I am not sure the question is clear because; f1's callback is f2, f2's callback is f3. <- answer?

Answer (score 1):

We also have similar, problem might not be exactly the same. we use `$.when` that JQuery provided.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

This example is copied from above link

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```